# Need help finding documentation on authoring command links

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am writing online help for my Eclipse plug-in. I want to create live help with command links to provide quick access to the Help->Install New Software in Eclipse. The 'Embedding commands in help' page in the Platform Plug-in Developer Guide suggests there are "a large number of useful commands already defined in the workbench".

Unfortunately, after a some search I seem to be unable to find documentation on the available commands I can use as parameters to executeCommand() in my link.

Can you please tell me what parameter to use to create a link to Help->Install New Software in Eclipse and also point me to the documentation of other available commands if such exists at all.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command id for Install New Software is `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.install`

I found this using the Eclipse `Search / Plug-in Search` and searching for the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point (which is used to define commands). I then looked at the search results until I found the correct command.